# qemu: could not load PC BIOS 'bios.bin' in Mountain Lion

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-emulator-plugin

I upgraded my mac installing, Mountain Lion 10.8.4 but now "Eclipse" goes into error every time I try to load an Android AVD. The error that returns is this:

qemu: could not load PC BIOS 'bios.bin'

help me to solve this problem?
  thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message on Windows when trying to run the x86 emulator. What worked for me was to find the "bios.bin" and "vgabios-cirrus.bin" files somewhere in C:\, and copy them to the folder ....\android-sdk-windows\tools.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass bios arguments (`$ANDROID_HOME/tools/lib/pc-bios`) to qemu:

```
emulator64-x86 -avd <avd_name> -qemu -L $ANDROID_HOME/tools/lib/pc-bios
```